# Why does PowerShell script fail on NAS Networks Share

Tags: powershell, recursion, count

I'm pretty new to PowerShell and have modified a script I found. It works like I expect it to locally on my windows computer (C:\ Drive). But when I run it over my network by changing the path to a network share on a NAS it lists all the directories correctly but all the file counts are zero.

I'm trying to find the file count in all directories and sub directories.

Here is the script:

```
Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object FullName, @{Name="FileCount";Expression={(Get-ChildItem $_ -File | Measure-Object).Count }}
```

C:\MyDirectory\Script = perfect

\\MyNetworkShare\MyDirectory\Script = proper directory listing but all file counts zero

What I'd ultimately like to do is find just directories with only a single (1) file in them. Can't do that till I get the NAS vs local thing figured out.

Thanks!

Added .FullName as suggested. Here is what the output looks like over network and locally. Can it be something with odd directories as I'm trying to manage a music library and lots of odd characters.

[image]

Comment: No it does not. I'm going to try and update question with a picture. Curious if the path length or characters used could be an issue.

Comment: The problem with the calculated properties "expression" is that it will not display any error message. Check your `$error` variable, see if the errors there give you a hint on the possible issue (`$error[0].Exception`, `$error[1].Exception` and so on)

Comment: Appreciate the idea @Santiago Squarzon. I'm unclear on how to do that. Will try to read up on it. It does not generate any "red error text" in the output window, like I've seen when I've had problems in the past.

Comment: When I run it locally I get lots of info (Mode, Write Time, Length, etc.) along with all the files names in every directory. When I run it over the network on a directory I know has files it just pauses and returns to command line. Again, I appreciate the help. I seem to be out of my element here.

Comment: I believe the problem might be that your paths have `[` and `]` which are special characters on WIndows (iirc) can't test that on Linux but, using `-LiteralPath` might solve the problem. Try this against your NAS: `Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory | % { Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Big thanks to @Santiago Squarzon! The solution was in fact to add -LiteralPath as noted in his comments. So the working script is:

```
Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory | Select-Object FullName, @{Name="FileCount";Expression={(Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $_.FullName -File | Measure-Object).Count }}
```

And initially testing on local dive with "normal" directory names vs the very long odd ones for showing music release data must have been breaking things.

Comment: glad it worked :) I realized the issue after seeing the screenshot. for future reference, `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidPathChars()` and `[System.IO.Path]::GetInvalidFileNameChars()` will help you know which characters you should never use

Answer (score 1):

It's not a one-liner but could prove useful?

```
Clear-Host
$rootFolder = '\\ComputerMentor2\CMShared\NAS-Downloads'
Get-ChildItem $rootFolder -Recurse -Directory | 
     Select-Object @{Name="FileCount";
     Expression={([Array](Get-ChildItem -Path "$($_.Fullname)" -filter "*.*" -File)).count}},
     @{Name="Path from Root";Expression={($_.FullName.Substring(($rootFolder.Length)+1))}} |
Sort -Property "Path from Root"
```

Sample Output:

```
FileCount Path from Root                                                      
--------- --------------                                                      
        1 Calibre EBook Software                                              
        4 iPad Stuff                                                          
        1 LibreOffice                                                         
        1 No Longer Available Software                                        
        3 No Longer Available Software\Macrium                                
        1 No Longer Available Software\MS Money                               
        2 Peripheral Software                                                 
        1 Peripheral Software\AMD                                             
        9 Purchased Software                                                  
        1 SanDisk                                                             
       43 Test                                                                
       27 Useful-Utilities                                                    
        1 Useful-Utilities\DG Readiness Tool                                  
          Useful-Utilities\DG Readiness Tool\dgreadiness_v3.6                 
        6 Useful-Utilities\DG Readiness Tool\dgreadiness_v3.6\dgreadiness_v3.6
        4 Useful-Utilities\Folder Marker Home                                 
        5 Useful-Utilities\Free File Sync                                     
        5 Useful-Utilities\Go Contact Sync Mod                                
        9 Useful-Utilities\GRC                                                
        3 Useful-Utilities\irFanView                                          
        3 Useful-Utilities\MiniTool Partition Wizard                          
        3 Useful-Utilities\NirSoft                                            
        4 Useful-Utilities\Samsung                                            
        1 Useful-Utilities\SARA                                               
        5 Video Codecs                                                        
        5 Windows Kits
```

Note: Dir with no count has no files!